# eval works on command line but not in script file

Tags: scheme, racket

Following simple `'eval'` statement works well on command line of DrRacket (as mentioned on https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html ):

```
> (eval '(+ 1 2))
3
```

However, if kept in the script file (main area of DrRacket) and run, it produces error:

```
#lang racket

(eval '(+ 1 2))
```

Error:

```
+: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: +
>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to use eval on user input in Racket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37246033/unable-to-use-eval-on-user-input-in-racket)

Comment: You should refer to the interactions in DrRacket as either the interactions window or the repl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Racket, this is the correct way to run `eval` inside a script:

```
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))


(eval '(+ 1 2) ns)
=> 3
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html#%28part._.Namespaces_and_.Modules%29).

Comment: Why does it work on the command line without any define-namespace-anchor?

Comment: @rnso in the command line, `current-namespace` is set to the namespace of the file. In the window, you have to explicitly set it yourself, or pass a second parameter to `eval`.